# Change Azure Webjobs schedule using C# code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I want to change the Azure webjobs schedule linked to an App Service. One way I was able to find was to use the [Webjobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API), but this would require API calls and credential management.

Is there any other way to do this using C# code, by maybe changing some environment settings ?

Comment: You mean set the schedule for a triggered job? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#cron-expressions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to do this using C# code, by maybe changing some environment settings ?

If you do not want to change Azure webjobs schedule by calling KuDu API, you could try to modify the `settings.job` to update the schedule.

Here is an example schedule that will run once every minute:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
}
```

**In Visual Studio**:

·Add the `settings.job` file at the root of your WebJob console app.
·Under the file's properties, set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.
·Then when you deploy the webjob, it will be deployed and act as Schedule.
For full sample, you could refer to this [git share](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/WebAppWithWebJobsVS).

**In KUDU**:

The `settings.job` file must be located at the root of the WebJob's folder, along side your WebJob's script such as in `wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\{job name}`

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob).

**Call KUDU API**:

The WebJob API require `Basic Authentication` using the [publishing credentials](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/using-the-azure-webjob-api/), you could go to your webapp in azure portal to click `Get publish profile` and **download** it to get `username` and `userpassword`.

Refer to the following code you could reset the schedule.

```
string userName = "$xxxxxxxxx";
string userPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string webAppName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{userName}:{userPassword}"));
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + "/api/triggeredwebjobs/{your_job_name}/settings";
    string body = "{\"schedule\": \"0 */2 * * * *\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this solution is not feasible if we have to change the schedule at runtime. This would require changing the file and deploying the app service again.

Comment: If you want to change the schedule at runtime, you have to call KuDu API to achieve it.